# How to make a GET request using a filter on a datetime property with EspoCRM REST API?

Tags: rest, espocrm

EspoCRM provides a REST API that sadly has only [incomplete documentation](https://github.com/espocrm/documentation/blob/master/development/api.md). Especially the filters that can be used with a GET request are [not documented](https://github.com/espocrm/documentation/blob/master/development/api.md#list-entities):

> `where` - (array) filters;

From using Firebug I've discovered that a filter consists of three query parameters:

- `where[0][field]=somefield`
- `where[0][type]=somoperator`
- `where[0][value]=somevalue`

**Example,** filter on `name=Foo`:

```
?where[0][field]=name&where[0][type]=equals&where[0][value]=Foo
```

The meaning of `equals` is not documented, as are the possible filter types.

Now I want to filter a collection on a `datetime` field `modifiedAt`. I have no idea what the proper values for `type` and `value` would be to find all entities that have been modified after a given datetime.

How can the EspoCRM REST API be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the EspoCRM web GUI, I was able to make a search that uses the filter I need. The query parameters are:

- `where[0][type]=after`
- `where[0][field]=modifiedAt`
- `where[0][value]=2016-06-01 16:12:00`
- `where[0][dateTime]=true`
- `where[0][timeZone]=Europe%2FBerlin`

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to find some more info about this, especially about the [type] operators, any idea? thank you!